# VS code clang-format extension not working in wsl

Tags: visual-studio-code, clang-format, vscode-remote

I am using vscode and the Xaver Clang-format extension via Wsl with a custon .clang-format file.
The extension does nothing when I save the file and when I select the option from the right click menu, I am however able to use clang format via the wsl terminal with `clang-format -style=file -i "Path to my file"`

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"clang-format.executable": "/home/fede/skyward-boardcore/.clang-format",
"clang-format.style": "file",
```

This is the part relative to the extension in my settings.json file.
I am using Windows 11 pro Version   10.0.22000 Build 22000 with Ubuntu 20.04.3 and vscode version 1.63.
Does anybody know how to fix this? Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

clang-format.executable would be the location of clang-format:

```
"clang-format.executable": "/usr/bin/clang-format",
```